# Is UNIX System V's source still available?

Tags: unix-philosophy, historical-unix

I was wondering if the AT&T system V's source code still available.

Comment: System III sources can be found easily. Due to contemporary legal issues, I am not so sure about system V

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may be awkward but I am answering my own question. I found out the source code: https://archive.org/details/ATTUNIXSystemVRelease4Version2